# htaccess redirect specific url from url get paramter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hello I have this link:

```
exemple.com/imageget.php?width=351&height=245&image=http://pic.exemple.com/images/marganit/266.jpg
```

the parameter "image" in

```
exemple.com/imageget.php
```

Is dynamic and I need to extract this parameter like this:

```
http://pic.exemple.com/images/marganit/266.jpg
```

And redirect the page to

```
http://pic.exemple.com/marganit/266.jpg
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: First of all you should fix the process that generates the URL, since it is invalid. You need to `urlencode()` the embedded URL: http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^width=\d+&height=\d+&image=(.*)(/images)(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %1%3? [R=301]
```

Test it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=cc1371f6-4c99-5233-bce0-e27d5345a55d).

Comment: Brrr processing URLs with regular expressions... brrr

Comment: @arkascha well, I like to try weird & bizarre things op can choose to ignore this.

Comment: hi thanks! i sorry but i made a mistake i need to redirect without the /images , from exemple.com/imageget.php?width=351&height=245&image=http://pic.exemple.com/images/marganit/266.jp  to http://pic.exemple.com/marganit/266.jpg